# How do I write multiple conditions and rules for .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in an .htaccess file for my website

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?membername=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^poem/(.*)/?$ poem.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>


# Works
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?membername=$1 [L]
# Does not work
RewriteRule ^poem/(.*)/?$ poem.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

If change it all to this bellow then the outcome is reversed.

```
# No longer works:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?membername=$1 [L]
# Now works:
RewriteRule ^poem/(.*)/?$ poem.php?id=$1 [L,NC]


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?membername=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^poem/(.*)/?$ poem.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

What's going on? I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like what you need to do here is to keep the negative tests on `REQUEST_FILENAME` and reverse the order of the rules. Otherwise, the more generic `^(.*)` always matches first, and overrules `^poem/`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # Negative conditions here...
    # Using REQUEST_FILENAME instead of SCRIPT_FILENAME
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # Match the more specific rule first...
    RewriteRule ^poem/(.*)/?$ poem.php?id=$1 [L,NC]

    # Match the generic rule last.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?membername=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've just found that if I place RewriteRule ^poem/(.*)/?$ poem.php?id=$1 [L,NC] before the conditions they both work perfectly.